# Query runs on SQL Server but doesn't with PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I wrote an SQL query for SQL Server and it works perfectly in SQL Server Management studio. However, when I run the same query within my PHP code it returns an error "Incorrect syntax at '='". I've run different queries before which ran fine.

```
$SQL = "SELECT MAX(EventTime) AS EventTime, UserID
    FROM [Net2Events].[dbo].[Events] e
    WHERE EventType = 20 AND
    Address = 5044830 AND
    NOT EXISTS (Select Max(EventTime) AS EventTime
                FROM [Net2Events].[dbo].[Events] e2
                WHERE  Address = 5042486 AND
                e2.EventTime > e.EventTime AND
                e2.UserId = e.UserId AND
                EventType = 20
                GROUP BY UserId)
    GROUP BY UserID";
```

Comment: How did you attempt to run the query?

Comment: $results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $SQL);

Comment: Please modify your post and add the exact and complete message that you are getting.

Comment: Currently this is the only information I have about the issue. I won't be able to post  the full error line until monday

Comment: Then, it's impossible to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping all instanced of the column "Address" in square brackets. It's a SQL Server keyword, and it might be confusing the driver.

```
$SQL = "SELECT MAX(EventTime) AS EventTime, UserID
    FROM [Net2Events].[dbo].[Events] e
    WHERE EventType = 20 AND
    [Address] = 5044830 AND
    NOT EXISTS (Select Max(EventTime) AS EventTime
                FROM [Net2Events].[dbo].[Events] e2
                WHERE  [Address] = 5042486 AND
                e2.EventTime > e.EventTime AND
                e2.UserId = e.UserId AND
                EventType = 20
                GROUP BY UserId)
    GROUP BY UserID";
```

Comment: First thing I'll try on monday! Wish I had a remote connection set up :/

Answer (score 1):

Try running the query like so:

```
$result = mssql_query('SELECT MAX(EventTime) AS EventTime, UserID
FROM [Net2Events].[dbo].[Events] e
WHERE EventType = 20 AND
Address = 5044830 AND
NOT EXISTS (Select Max(EventTime) AS EventTime
            FROM [Net2Events].[dbo].[Events] e2
            WHERE  Address = 5042486 AND
            e2.EventTime > e.EventTime AND
            e2.UserId = e.UserId AND
            EventType = 20
            GROUP BY UserId)
GROUP BY UserID');
```

Comment: I'm using sqlsrv, not mssql :/

Comment: Oh, shoot, oversight on my part. Is there a reason you are tied to using sqlsrv?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it all one one single line. I know it looks horrible, but it will help you see if you need to cater for the string being on multiple lines in a different way.

```
$SQL = "SELECT MAX(EventTime) AS EventTime, UserID FROM [Net2Events].[dbo].[Events] e WHERE EventType = 20 AND Address = 5044830 AND NOT EXISTS (Select Max(EventTime) AS EventTime FROM [Net2Events].[dbo].[Events] e2 WHERE  Address = 5042486 AND e2.EventTime > e.EventTime AND e2.UserId = e.UserId AND EventType = 20 GROUP BY UserId) GROUP BY UserID";
```

If it works then you have narrowed down the problem. You could try adding a blank space to the end of each line.